# C++ template errors with implementation in CPP file (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, templates, inheritance

I have a C++ class definition declared in a header file as follows:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass : public T
{

public:

    STDMETHODIMP myMethod();

};
```

The implementation in a .cpp is this:

```
template <class T>
STDMETHODIMP MyClass<T>::myMethod() {
// Implementation...
}
```

The compiler (Visual Studio) is complaining about the method implementation, saying that "anachronism used : modifiers on data ignored" and also "unrecognizable template declaration / definition".

Any ideas what's going wrong?

EDIT:

Might the error be here?

I am trying to extend MyClass, so I declare

```
class ChildClass : MyClass<SomeConcreteClass>
{
// Stuff...
};
```

Comment: If you want to keep your headers clean, you can write it into a .inl file and simply include "<implementation>.inl" at the end of your header

Answer (score 0):

1. The definition of the template function has to be in the header file too. (The only exception to this rule is if the template is only instantiated in one compilation unit; in which case you can put the definitions in the same source.). So move the implementation out of the `.cpp` and into the header.
2. Your writing `STDMETHODIMP` in the class declaration looks suspect as well (and is probably the source of the immediate error). Are you sure there's not another macro like `STDMETHOD` that you should be using there?

Comment: that isn't the only exception, you can also explicitly instantiate in the header and then define the implementation in the cpp file. But that's like, a super edge case that no one ever uses.

Comment: STDMETHOD includes "virtual", the only difference with STDMETHODIMP so should I be using it? This is a COM class by the way. Even having moved the impl into the header I'm still getting "unnamed class template"

Comment: For now, use STDMETHOD in the class declaration and include the definition of the function there too. Fix the compile errors, verify the runtime, then separate out the implementation.

Comment: Might the issue be somewhere else? If I am extending MyClass, is this ok: class My2ndClass : public MyClass<AnotherClass>